# What does "1<" accomplish?

Tags: zsh, io-redirection

I'm trying to understand how the shell handles redirection a little bit better. My understanding is that the syntax "n<" means to redirect the file descriptor given by "n."

The command I'm struggling to understand is

```
echo "first" > test; echo "second" 1< test
```

What I thought would happen is that the file "test" would be overwritten with the text "first"; then, when the second command executed, 1--i.e., stdout--would be redirected to test.

What actually happens is the following:

1. Nothing writes to terminal, so stdout was redirected *somewhere*;
2. When I open "test," what's written is "first" rather than "second," so I didn't overwrite "test."

Can anyone explain what's going on? Is it that stdout is being redirected to test but in "readonly" mode or something like that? I can't find any reference to using `1<` in a script elsewhere (since, admittedly, it seems like a strange thing to do).

Comment: Where did you get this snippet from?

Comment: When I run `echo "second" 1< test`, I get an error `bash: echo: write error: Bad file descriptor`. Do you also get that error? If not, what version of Bash are you using?

Comment: My mistake--I thought I was running it using Bash, but actually zsh was interpreting the command. I have updated accordingly. Thank you! (P.S.: When I run in Bash 3.2, I get the same error.)

Comment: Maybe you wanted `1>foo`, the open-for-write version? Though that's exactly the same as just `>foo`, since stdout is the default descriptor when doing a redirection for write (as stdin, 0, is the default descriptor when doing a redirection for read).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shell redirection `1<foo` makes FD 1, aka stdout -- normally an *output* descriptor -- connected to a *read-only* handle on file `foo`.

Thus, when `echo` tries to *write* to that *read-only* handle, it will fail; in most reasonable shells, this will also write an error message to stderr.

In this context, that code serves no purpose, and is simply a bug; you'd need to have a program that tried to read from FD 1 (perhaps assuming that to be a connection to the current terminal) for it to be meaningful. (That said, any program that did this would be buggy itself; reads should be done, if not through FD 0, from a handle direct on `/dev/tty`).